# Getting wrong contacts number in listview when Ascending it according to name

Tags: android

I want to display contact list in ascending order so I used "ASC" order in query but after doing this name on contacts is in ascending order but it display wrong number for person how I resolve this issue.

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public ArrayList<String> namelist;
    public ArrayList<String> numberlist;
    public ArrayList<Integer> CheckedItem;
    public ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getAllContacts();
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,namelist,numberlist,CheckedItem));
    }
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public void getAllContacts()
    {
        namelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        numberlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                //Cursor phones = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, "ASC");
                Cursor cur = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            namelist.add(name);
            numberlist.add(phoneNumber);
            Log.d("NAMELIST:",namelist.toString());
            Log.d("NAMELIST:",numberlist.toString());




        cur.close();
    }
    class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<String> {
          public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
            return strA.compareToIgnoreCase(strB);
          }
        }
    private static void sortList(List<String> aItems){
        Collections.sort(aItems, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
      }
    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<String> NAME_LIST;
        ArrayList<String> NUMBER_LIST;
        ArrayList<Integer> CHECKEDITEM;

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Activity activity;

        public CustomAdapter(Activity a,ArrayList<String>name,ArrayList<String> number,ArrayList<Integer> checkitem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            NAME_LIST = name;
            NUMBER_LIST = number;

            activity = a;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return NAME_LIST.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;

        }

        public class Holder {
            TextView tv1;
            TextView tv2;
            CheckBox chk;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View mView = convertView;

            if (mView == null) {

                final LayoutInflater sInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                mView = sInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, false);

            }

            final TextView txv1 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            final TextView txv2 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.number);


            txv1.setText(NAME_LIST.get(position));
            txv2.setText(NUMBER_LIST.get(position));
            return txv1;



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you notify adapter after setAdapter() method ?

Comment: no,where I notify it?

Comment: first create object of custom adapter and than bind it

Comment: I set Adapter in listview in oncreate method like this.

Comment: lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,namelist,numberlist,CheckedItem)); after that I notify it?

Comment: Please check your code i modified it @Nidhi Dave

Comment: You can use HashMap. In this key as a name & value as a number. & after add all contact in hashmap sort this hashmap using it's key. @NidhiDave

Comment: Its better to take follow the Bean structure for storing the name and phone number.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to load numbers and names with Names Ascending

```
         Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
           while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
              String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
              String phoneNumberString = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              Log.e(name, phoneNumberString);
              namelist.add(name);
              numberlist.add(phoneNumberString);
            }             //The problem in your code is you need to close this bracket, and call phones.close() after all the items are fetched.Your code calls phone.close() everytime
            phones.close();
```

Comment: Yes my problem is resolved but now I have one issue regarding displaying record in listview after reaching last contact it display first contact again and again how I solve this?

Comment: when I scroll listview I reached at last contact and after that it display me first record again  means contacts is not stopped at last record.

Comment: its because you didn't clear the list. call `namelist.clear()` and `numberlist.clear()`

Comment: before calling this function.

Comment: Cool . Mark it accepted if it helped. So other users can find solution immediately

Comment: but still there is one probliem in listview it display me some contacts from A to Z after that it display me remaining contacts in a to z means two time record displayed with different contacts in a to z manner how I solve this?